# $this->url() to another subdomain

Tags: php, zend-framework, dns, routes, subdomain

I created subdomain for my application.

```
host_www.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
host_www.route = "www.mywebsite.com"
host_www.defaults.module = "default"
host_www.defaults.controller = "index"
host_www.defaults.action = "index"

store_infos.route = "storeinfos/:store"
store_infos.defaults.controller = "store"
store_infos.defaults.action = "store-infos"
store_infos.defaults.module = "default"
store_infos.chain = "host_www"

host_products.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
host_products.route = "products.mywebsite.com"
host_products.defaults.module = "products"
host_products.defaults.controller = "products"
host_products.defaults.action = "index"

product_infos.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
product_infos.route = "([-\w]+).htm"
product_infos.reverse = "%s.htm"
product_infos.map.1 = "q"
product_infos.defaults.module = "products"
product_infos.defaults.controller = "products"
product_infos.defaults.action = "see-product"
product_infos.chain = "host_products"
```

I don't know if the syntax in this zend config ini file is correct, in particular for routes chaining.

Once I'm on this subdomain, urls constructed with $this->url() like this :

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('store' => 1234), 'store_infos', true) ?>">
See store informations
</a>
```

still point to the subdomain products.mywebsite.com, where I want it to point to www.mywebsite.com

For the moment, I do this :

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com<?= $this->url(array('store' => 1234), 'store_infos', true) ?>">
See store informations
</a>
```

But it's not flexible at all.

Is there a solution, a parameter to add, or my config file is wrong ?

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do so many people use non-english variable names/array keys in their code? While it's not important for that question, it makes code hardly understandable by people not speaking your language since understanding variable/function names is usually a great aid in understanding code.

Comment: sorry, forgotten to translate many variables.
I understand your point of view, and I'm agree.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in you index.php, define the server part of the address:

```
// Define the server
defined('APPLICATION_SERVER')
    || define('APPLICATION_SERVER', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

And then use:

```
<a href="http://<?=APPLICATION_SERVER."/".$this->url(array('store'=>'1234'))?>">
```